# Como arredondar idade com PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, data

Usei a função `age()`, abaixo, para calcular a idade, a partir de uma data armazenada em uma tabela:

```
select pessoa.*, age(data_nascimento) from pessoa;
```

Retornou o intervalo: **27 years 9 months 9 days**

É possível arredondar esse intervalo apenas para 27 anos ou 27 *years*?

O SGBD utilizado: PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eu gosto de usar o `to_char`, traz muitas possibilidades, segue exemplo de funções diversas:

```
select *,
   date_part('year', age(data_nascimento))||' Anos' AS idade,
   date_trunc('year', age(data_nascimento)) AS idade2,
   extract(year from age(data_nascimento))||' Anos' AS idade3,
   to_char(age(data_nascimento),'yy Anos') as idade4
from pessoa
```

Mais informações do `to_char`
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-formatting.html

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar a função `date_part` http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-datetime.html